# Are there any good and free graphical administration tools for SQLlite on the mac?

Tags: sqlite, database-administration

I know there is an SQLite Manager Extension for Firefox but, really, I don't like to do that from within a Web Browser. That's totally uncool. And I don't want to install Firefox just for that. ;)

I hope there are other good tools, although that firefox option doesn't look too bad. But let's see if there's something better out there...

Answer (score 1):

There is a Firefox extension which I found quite useful:

[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)

This should work on OSX too ...

Comment: Just to note: The original question didn't mention the firefox extension, so the answer made sense ...